# Orbits for a subgroup $H$ of $G$ acting on $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Why the orbits for a subgroup of $H$ of $G$ acting on $G$ by **left** multiplication are the **right** cosets of $H$ in $G$?

Comment: This is just defnitions: Fix $g\in G$. Then the map $(h,g)\to hg$ is an action of $H$ on $G$ and its image is the right coset $Hg$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g\in G$, then the orbit of $g$ under this action is
$$\mathcal{O}_g = \{hg\,|\,h\in H\} = Hg,$$
which is just the right coset of $H$ containing $g$.